# Can someone find a (two-sided) inverse function to the characteristic function χ? given...

Tags: inverse, characteristic-functions

so i have given the folowing info:

In general, if $A$ is a set, for $S \in \mathcal P(A)$ define $\chi(S) : A \to \{0,1\}$ by $$\chi(S)(a) = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } a \in S, \\ 0 & \textrm{if } a \notin S. \end{cases}$$
Then $\chi : \mathcal P(A) \to 2^A$ is bijective.

But I would like to know the what the inverse is to $\chi$. I'm quite new with the definition "characteristic function", so I don't even now how to start. I normally calculate the inverse by replacing x with y and vice versa, but know I don't have a clue. Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see my hint of the characteristic function came into good use! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an $f\in 2^A$, then $f$ is a function from $A$ to $2=\{0,1\}$. So you need to associate $f$ with a subset $F\subseteq A$. As the comment above said, take the inverse image of 1 under $f$, that is, $F=\{a\in A : f(a)=1\}$.
So, you have a function from $2^A$ to $\mathcal P (A)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Given $f \in 2^A$, define $\chi^{-1}(f) = \{a \in A \mid f(a)=1\} \in \mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: So when it comes down to a characteristic function, this is the inverse? But isn't it then that every function can be be whritten as an inverse function? Or am I wrong please correct me if I am. Btw. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: $\chi$ is a function whose domain is $\mathcal P(A)$ and whose range is $2^A$. So it's inverse $\chi^{-1}$ is a function whose domain is $2^A$ and whose range is $\mathcal P(A)$. So, to each element $f \in 2^A$ we must associate an element $\chi^{-1}(f) \in \mathcal P(A)$. That's what my answer does. The fact that $f$ is a function and $\chi$ is also a function, should not be confused with each other.